# How to make Verital and Horizontal scroll on 2 layouts?

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to make Layout that contains 2 layout, vertical and horizontal scrolls.

Like this :
http://202.131.244.11/demo/VerticalAndHorizontalScrolls.PNG

How to make it ?
I've tried it. But horizontal scroll doesn't work for me.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your layout xml look like?  Presumably, you want a hierarchy like this:

```
ScrollView
    ViewGroup (some sort of layout to contain everything)
        ViewGroup (layout 1)
        HorizontalScrollView
            ViewGroup (layout 2)
```